# Firebase Does not build for IOS in Flutter - Implicit declaration of function 'pb_release' is invalid in C99

Tags: firebase, flutter, cocoapods

When I add firebase_core: ^1.11.0 to my pubspec.yaml I cannot manage to run on IOS, it does run on Android.

I am getting an error

```
ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCCTLibrary/GDTCCTUploadOperation.m:408:3: error: implicit declaration of function
'pb_release' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      pb_release(gdt_cct_BatchedLogRequest_fields, &batchedLogRequest);
```

This is from the Podfile lock

```
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (8.11.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 9.1)
```

I see the same error when trying to run with XCode

I am using Flutter 2.8.1 on a Mac 11.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to have been causing the issue is some code I had at the end of my Podfile, from the permission_handler plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
                'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
                'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
                'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',
             ]
        end
  end
end
```

The problem is that if I remove this from the Podfile I do not have the correct permissions for devices in the app settings

---- Update  ----

I was missing the line

```
'$(inherited)',
```

At the top after

```
  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
    '$(inherited)',
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you figured this out, but it's spot on. I had the exact same conflict with firebase and permission handler when building on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

`pb_release` is defined in the pb_decode.h included at the top of `GDTCCTUploadOperation.m`:

[image]

Something in your Xcode project configuration might be messing with the definition of `PB_ENABLE_MALLOC`